# Expand dataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a dataFrame like

```
import pandas as pd

current = pd.DataFrame([{
    'a1': 'ab',
    'a2': 'value'
}, {
    'a1': 'ef',
    'a2': 'value'
}])
```

I need to create a new dataFrame like below.

```
new = pd.DataFrame([{
    'a1': 'ab',
    'a2': 'value',
    'a1Val': 'a'
 }, {
    'a1': 'ab',
    'a2': 'value',
    'a1Val': 'b'
 }, {
    'a1': 'ef',
    'a2': 'value',
    'a1Val': 'e'
 }, {
    'a1': 'ef',
    'a2': 'value',
    'a1Val': 'f'
 }])
```

Iterating through a dataFrame with `iterrows()` or `itertuples()` and modifying or adding rows to a newDatafromve with `df.loc()` seems like extremely slow.

How can I create a dataFrame or modify the `current` like `new` in a faster way ?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do? Without a well formulated problem these kind of questions (where you only have input-output pairs) generally receive solutions that works for the sample but do not generalize.

Comment: I am just doing a data manipulation, basically looking for ideas to create df without for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need create `Series` with `string`s, reshape by `stack` and `join` to original `DataFrame`:

```
s = (current['a1'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
                  .stack()
                  .rename('a1val')
                  .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
print (s)
0    a
0    b
1    e
1    f
Name: a1val, dtype: object

df = current.join(s).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   a1     a2 a1val
0  ab  value     a
1  ab  value     b
2  ef  value     e
3  ef  value     f
```

Another solution with `numpy`, first convert `a1` to `list`s and repeat `index` by `length`s for new `DataFrame` created by `loc`. Last add new column with `concatenate`:

```
s = current['a1'].apply(list)
l = s.str.len()
df = (current.loc[current.index.repeat(l)]
            .assign(a1val=np.concatenate(s.values))
            .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   a1     a2 a1val
0  ab  value     a
1  ab  value     b
2  ef  value     e
3  ef  value     f
```